# pysnmp snmpwalk giving timeouterror

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I am able to run snmpwalk from my machine

snmpwalk -c public -v 2c junipertestrtr 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1 from the same computer's command line I get the right output

iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.254.83.1.172.16.25.82 = Gauge32: 64902 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.254.135.1.172.17.25.134 = Gauge32: 64902 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.29.255.136 = Gauge32: 64861 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.28.255.137 = Gauge32: 64861 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.172.28.255.135.1.172.28.255.138 = Gauge32: 64861 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2636.5.1.1.2.1.1.1.13.0.1.10.1.1.1.1.10.1.1.2 = Gauge32: 64810

However when I try to run the same from pysnmp, I get a failure

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.smi import *


cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBind = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public', 1),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('junipertestrtr', 161)),
    (1,3,6,1,4,1,2636,5,1,1,2,1,1,1,13,0,1),

)

print errorIndication, errorStatus

for varBindTableRow in varBind:
    for name, val in varBindTableRow:
        print name, val
```

I get the below error message
 "requestTimedOut 0"

Answer (score 0):

You should be using just:

```
cmdgen.CommunityData('public')
```

or:

```
cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=1)  # mpModel specifies SNMP protocol version
```

or:

```
cmdgen.CommunityData('my-snmp-agent', 'public', 1)
```

You could also enable pysnmp debugging at the beginning of your script to see what's going on under the hood:

```
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc', 'secmod'))
```

A bunch of examples are available at [pysnmp site](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c.html)